# Thousand separator in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is get 5888 to look like 5,888 when my html is run any help would be appreciated. So after you run this in html I want the countdown of "xxxx hours unitl xmas". What the question is I want the "xxxx" to be as "x,xxx".

```
    <html>
<body>

<p>Clock!</p>
<div id = "string"></div>
<div id = "string2"></div>

<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer()
{
var d=new Date();
var n=d.toLocaleDateString(); 
var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
var m = d.toTimeString(); 
document.getElementById("string").innerHTML= n + m;

var b = new Date();
b.setFullYear(2014,11,25); 
var dateHour1 = b.getTime();
var minutes=1000*60;
var hours=minutes*60;
var xHour = Math.round((dateHour1 - d)/hours);
document.getElementById("string2").innerHTML = xHour +" Hours until xmas";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a function like:

```
// Format a number n using: 
//   p decimal places (two by default)
//   ts as the thousands separator (comma by default) and
//   dp as the  decimal point (period by default).
//
//   If p < 0 or p > 20 results are implementation dependent.
function formatNumber(n, p, ts, dp) {
  var t = [];
  // Get arguments, set defaults
  if (typeof p  == 'undefined') p  = 2;
  if (typeof ts == 'undefined') ts = ',';
  if (typeof dp == 'undefined') dp = '.';

  // Get number and decimal part of n
  n = Number(n).toFixed(p).split('.');

  // Add thousands separator and decimal point (if requied):
  for (var iLen = n[0].length, i = iLen? iLen % 3 || 3 : 0, j = 0; i <= iLen; i+=3) {
    t.push(n[0].substring(j, i));
    j = i;
  }
  // Insert separators and return result
  return t.join(ts) + (n[1]? dp + n[1] : '');
}

formatNumber(5888, 0) // 5,888
```

Comment: I'm actually using notepad++ to edit my html, would be helpful if this was in html format.